# Low iops,read and write performances

Tags: performance, iops

We are currently testing our using ZFS on Linux as a storage platform for our VPS nodes but we don't seem to be getting the performance figures we expected. Can you please provide some suggestions as to what we should be tweaking to reach higher iops?

Hardware is SuperMicro with the MegaRAID 2108 chipset as a daughter card on each server. We had three servers that we tested: pure SSD with 4 x 480GB Chronos drives, 4 x 600GB SAS 10k drives and 480GB SSD cache, and lastly 4 x 1TB SAS 7.2k with 480GB SSD cache.

We set the onboard raid controller to essentially JBOD (raid0 per drive with cache turned off). We got the best performance when using Z2 with LZ4 compression.

It doesn't seem like there is a big difference between the pure SSD setup and the others, even without the SSD cache on the other setups. Is there something we are missing here or something we should be looking into? We were expecting iops to be a lot higher than the results.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hard to comment on results we can't see.

Answer (score 1):

Using a RAID0 per drive still goes through the RAID chipset which will hurt performance.

You'll get better performance by configuring each drive as an ACTUAL JBOD drive and the best performance by using an IT mode HBA (switch the HBA or flash it with IT firmware instead of IR)